# Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SDK_VERSION' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler

Tags: android, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have the following ionic cordova project:

/my-app/config.xml

```
<engine name="android" spec="^6.4.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.7" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-facebook4" spec="^2.4.0">
        <variable name="APP_ID" value="123456789" />
        <variable name="APP_NAME" value="my-app" />
    </plugin>
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" spec="^1.2.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="^4.1.0" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.3" />
    <plugin name="ionic-plugin-keyboard" spec="^2.2.1" />
```

/my-app/package.json

```
"cordova": {
        "plugins": {
            "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
                "APP_ID": "123456789",
                "APP_NAME": "my-app"
            },
            "cordova-plugin-device": {},
            "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
            "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
            "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
            "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {}
        },
        "platforms": [
            "android"
        ]
    }
```

When I run: `enter code here`ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2

global packages:

    Cordova CLI : 7.0.1 

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.0
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.4.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    Node : v8.11.4
    npm  : 5.6.0 
    OS   : Linux 4.15
```

**Context**:
When I run :`ionic cordova build android`

```
> ionic cordova prepare
> cordova prepare
✔ Running command - done!

> cordova build android
✖ Running command - failed!
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):


        ANDROID_HOME=/home/rreyes/android-sdk-linux
        JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
        Subproject Path: CordovaLib
        The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use 
        Task.doLast(Action) instead.
            at build_8oeka4t56dp9oa43kn5u8er7z.run(/home/rreyes/workspace/tennis-up-app/platforms/android/build.gradle:141)

        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * Where:
        Build file '/home/rreyes/workspace/tennis-up-app/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 255

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
        > Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SDK_VERSION' for object of type 
        org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

        BUILD FAILED in 2s
        Error: /home/rreyes/workspace/tennis-up-app/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error 
        output:
        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

        * Where:
        Build file '/home/rreyes/workspace/tennis-up-app/platforms/android/build.gradle' line: 255

        * What went wrong:
        A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
        > Could not get unknown property 'ANDROID_SDK_VERSION' for object of type 
        org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

        * Try:
        Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

        * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

        BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I did set an env variable for ANDROID_SDK_VESION ="4.+"

**Question**: What I need to do to get a build success running  `ionic cordova build android`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Already tried those comments and did not work. @Sana

Comment: In which file you declared `ANDROID_SDK_VESION `?

Comment: Could u post the file `/home/rreyes/workspace/tennis-up-app/platforms/android/build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `ANDROID_SDK_VERSION` variable in you project level `build.gradle` file, or you can define it in your `gradle.properties` file also.

In the project level `build.gradle` file:

```
project.ext {
variableName = value
}
```

- Access it using: `project.ext.variablename`
- And in gradle.properties file: `VariableName = value`
- Access it using: `$variableName`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused mostly due to the the geolocation plugin in cordova
try removing it and reinstalling (the latest)
cordova plugin list gives all the plugins
cordova plugin rm  would remove the plugin.

```
setting properties (project.properties) file to the following might resolve the issue:
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:9.2.1
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.2.1
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
```